# Why did this aggregation R code give the total sum rather than the monthly aggregation of daily expenses?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, aggregate, summary

In the typical result of the code below, the monthly column should has the monthly aggregations of daily expenses, which has 366 entries, while monthly should be 12 entries. Why did the code below give the total sum of one entry in the Monthly variable?

Although this link https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-02-22-group_by_month_r shows  the code leads to the desired outcome, the monthly aggregated 12 values!
So why my code which is exactly the same gives only the total sum, as it is shown in the screenshot of R studio on my laptop!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(2017)
#options(digits=4)

(expenses <- data_frame(
date=seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by=1),
amount=rgamma(length(date), shape = 2, scale = 20)))

Monthly<-expenses %>% group_by(month=floor_date(date, "month")) %>%
summarize(amount=sum(amount))

monthly2<-expenses %>% mutate(Mon=month(date), Day=day(date)) %>%
group_by(Mon,Day) %>%
```

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
Normal:  Inversion 
Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.7.4 plyr_1.8.4      XML_3.98-1.20   leaflet_2.0.2  
[5] raster_2.9-23   sp_1.3-1        elevatr_0.2.0   clifro_3.2-2   
[9] knitr_1.23      MASS_7.3-51.4   forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0  
[13] dplyr_0.8.3     purrr_0.3.2     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.3    
[17] tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.2.0   tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.2         lattice_0.20-38    utf8_1.1.4        
[4] assertthat_0.2.1   zeallot_0.1.0      digest_0.6.20     
[7] mime_0.7           R6_2.4.0           cellranger_1.1.0  
[10] backports_1.1.4    httr_1.4.0         pillar_1.4.2      
[13] rlang_0.4.0        curl_4.0           lazyeval_0.2.2    
[16] readxl_1.3.1       rstudioapi_0.10    labeling_0.3      
[19] htmlwidgets_1.3    RCurl_1.95-4.12    munsell_0.5.0     
[22] shiny_1.3.2        broom_0.5.2        compiler_3.6.1    
[25] httpuv_1.5.1       modelr_0.1.4       xfun_0.8          
[28] pkgconfig_2.0.2    htmltools_0.3.6    tidyselect_0.2.5  
[31] codetools_0.2-16   fansi_0.4.0        crayon_1.3.4      
[34] withr_2.1.2        later_0.8.0        bitops_1.0-6      
[37] grid_3.6.1         nlme_3.1-140       jsonlite_1.6      
[40] xtable_1.8-4       gtable_0.3.0       magrittr_1.5      
[43] scales_1.0.0       cli_1.1.0          stringi_1.4.3     
[46] reshape2_1.4.3     promises_1.0.1     xml2_1.2.1        
[49] generics_0.0.2     vctrs_0.2.0        RColorBrewer_1.1-2
[52] tools_3.6.1        glue_1.3.1         hms_0.5.0         
[55] crosstalk_1.0.0    yaml_2.2.0         colorspace_1.4-1  
[58] rvest_0.3.4        haven_2.1.1
```

Comment: You saved to `Monthly` but use `expenses`, is this a mistake? The aggregation code works as expected unless I misinterpreted your question. If you add this to the `dplyr` code, you get the same value: `%>% 
  summarise(sum(amount))`.

Comment: Thanks Nelson for your response.. so if this code gives the total sum, how could it be modified to get a column of monthly aggregated expenses rather than the total sum?

Comment: The code is correct. This is not correct(imho): `sum(expenses$amount)`. I think you meant just `Monthly$amount`.

Comment: If you want to be verbose: `expenses %>% 
  mutate(Mon=month(date), Day=day(date)) %>% 
  group_by(Mon) %>%  
  summarize(amount=sum(amount))`.

Comment: It is gives me the total sum in the monthly variable and I put this sum at the end to check out, and below is the original webpage where I found the code, but strangely for my case it gives me the sum rather than the monthly aggregations. I don't know why?  https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-02-22-group_by_month_r

Comment: What is your expected output? Could you edit your question to show what values you wish to get?

Comment: It is gives me the total sum in the monthly variable and I put this sum at the end to check out, and below is the original webpage where I found the code, but strangely for my case it gives me the sum rather than the monthly aggregations. I don't know why?! Is it a bug in my R?  https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-02-22-group_by_month_r

Comment: I've failed to understand what you need. The code gives the same results as your link. What are you trying to achieve with `sum(expenses$amount)`? `sum` does not perform any aggregation but takes the data as a whole. Did you run the code in my earlier comment?

Comment: I put sum(expenses$amount) just for checking out, because in the monthly variable I got one value rather than 12 values, and that is why I used sum(expenses$amount) to realize which value is! so I found it to be the sum. I know the link gives the 12 monthly aggregation values not the sum, and that is why I am surprised. Also tried your lines didn't work?! I don't know.. it could be a bug in R on my PC only!

Comment: You saved the output to `Monthly`. Why then do you check with `expenses`? In any case what's the point of using `sum`. Even if you used `sum` on Monthly$amount, you'd still get one value. `sum` **does not aggregate data**. Can you add the output of Monthly to your post?

Comment: Nelson, forget about sum... I've just removed it, and it still and I am wondering why the code on my PC doesn't lead to the same result of the code in the link although it is similar? I got one value rather than 12 values in the aggregation column in this link https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-02-22-group_by_month_r

Comment: Nelson I've edited the question and attached a screen shot of my R studio, and you can see that monthly and monthly 2 has just 1 value?!

Comment: Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your post, I personally can't reproduce your issue, maybe someone else can.

Comment: Yes, I did and thanks

Comment: @NelsonGon, it worked after restarting my PC!